# How to force my dataframe to keep its order?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I've made these two really basic dataframes:

```
CollaroyPrices<-data.frame(years=c("Jan-2023", "Feb-2023", "Mar-2023", "Apr-2023", "May-2023", "Jun-2023", "Jul-2023", 
                                   "Aug-2023", "Sep-2023", "Oct-2023", "Nov-2023", "Dec-2023"),
                          medianprice=c(2700000, 2740000, 2920000, 2990000, 3100000, 3210000, 3220000, 3180000, 3200000, 3200000, 3130000, 3120000))
                            

NSWPrices<-data.frame(years=c("Jan-2023", "Feb-2023", "Mar-2023", "Apr-2023", "May-2023", "Jun-2023", "Jul-2023", 
                              "Aug-2023", "Sep-2023", "Oct-2023", "Nov-2023", "Dec-2023"),
                      medianprice=c(949000, 955000, 958000, 969000, 980000, 993000, 1000000, 1000100, 1000200, 1000200, 1000300, 1000300))
```

When I run them the dataframes remain in the right order (as in, running from January to December):

```
> CollaroyPrices
      years medianprice
1  Jan 2023     2700000
2  Feb 2023     2740000
3  Mar 2023     2920000
4  Apr 2023     2990000
5  May 2023     3100000
6  Jun 2023     3210000
7  Jul 2023     3220000
8  Aug 2023     3180000
9  Sep 2023     3200000
10 Oct 2023     3200000
11 Nov 2023     3130000
12 Dec 2023     3120000
```

However when I make a basic line graph using ggplot2, it scrambles the x axis:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=CollaroyPrices, aes(x=years, y=medianprice, color="CollaroyPrices", group=1), size=1) +
  geom_line(data=NSWPrices, aes(x=years, y=medianprice, color="NSWPrices", group=1), size=1)
```

[image: scrambled x axis]

Is anyone able to help with making R keep the order I entered?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I figured it out,

```
library(forcats)
```

And then add fct_inorder to my ggplot to keep the order I plugged the factor variables in as:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=CollaroyPrices, aes(x=fct_inorder(years), y=medianprice, color="CollaroyPrices", group=1), size=1) +
  geom_line(data=NSWPrices, aes(x=fct_inorder(years), y=medianprice, color="NSWPrices", group=1), size=1)
```